# azure media services - How to secure my Video URL from users Downloading it?

Tags: plugins, azure, authorization, media

We are using Windows Media Server 2003 and 2008 for delivering videos on one of my project.

**Authorization URL Plugin** is enabled in it - By this i can generate a dynamic secure URL by forming a Hash code(With IP etc). So that the URL can not be bypassed or used by others.

Now i am planning to switch to Windows Azure Media Services, Can i configure Authorization Plugin or any such **security for my URL inside Azure**?

As i don't want users to access or steal my videos.

Best Regards,

Prasanth.k

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use any standard Windows Media Server plugins with Azure Media Services. But if you do take a look at the documentation, you will see that all media is protected by default in Azure Media Services:

- [How to: Deliver Asset by download (it is progressive download)](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/Media-Services/how-to-guides/media-services-dotnet/#download-asset)
- [How to: Deliver Asset by Streaming (smooth streaming or so)](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/Media-Services/how-to-guides/media-services-dotnet/#stream-asset)

If read carefully and follow all reference documentation you will see that first step of all actions is creating `AccessPolicy`. For example:

```
IAccessPolicy accessPolicy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("File Download Policy", TimeSpan.FromDays(30), AccessPermissions.Read);
```

So, you generally `can't` really provide plain/raw/full/limitless access to your assets, unless you really want to. In other words - content in Media Services is protected by default.